# Uninstall Faulty MSI --> System Crash

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash, operating-system, windows-installer, regedit

A few customers have an MSI installed on their system (servers and desktop's, winxp, win7, server2k8r2, server2012r2).

The MSI is created by a default VS2010 "Visual Studio Installer Setup Project".

There are 2 reg keys created with the installation.

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Silverlight\AllowElevatedTrustAppsInBrowser = 1
HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Silverlight\AllowElevatedTrustAppsInBrowser = 1
```

When uninstalling, on some system's, the whole Software\*\Microsoft node gets deleted.

Anyone got an idea how I can solve this, without crashing the systems.
(This already happened a few times, but there are still a lot of installations.)

---

The zip contains an exe that install's requirements + certificates + MSI.
The MSI itself is in the IG folder.

There is also an install.log & uninstall.log (from windows 7 virtual box)
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ku3vqoajfxbnluq/AACQ6evVw4pzRJ6WTzqCHR8Ba?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of a similar incident ( using InstallShield instead of VS but both create MSIs )

[InstallShield 2008 HOTFIX: COM Extraction Causes System Corruption during Uninstall](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2007/08/hotfix-com-extraction-causes-system.html)

Your question isn't directly answerable given the information.  I would need to evaluate the .MSI looking for custom actions, registry table entries and any self registering DLLs.  An uninstall log file would help also.  You might have to boot from recovery media to get to it but it should be there if you log the uninstall.

You should treat this as an emergency before many more clients are impacted.  Investigate root cause and issue a patch so that customers can safely uninstall.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get an uninstall log, but I can give you access to the msi.

Comment: Please send me an email with instructions on how to get to it.

Comment: Where can I find your email address?

Comment: I have added an url in the OP.

Comment: I've reviewd the MSI and I don't see anything that would be causing this. There's no custom actions other then the built in ones for checking .NET version.  There are no SelfReg table entries.  The Registry and RemoveRegistry tables look fine.   The only thing "wrong" that I see if the duplicate registry key for the Silverlight setting.   You shouldn't have an entry for Wow6432node.  The MSI is built for 32bit so when it tries to open the registry it'll automatically be given the correct place.

Comment: I reviewedd the uninstall.log and it's fine. I see there's an uninstall.bat with an innocent  msiexec /x {GUID}.   What calls this .BAT file?  Could that process be doing additional pre-uninstall cleanup?  If so, maybe it's deleting the registry key.

Comment: The bat file is the "easy uninstall starter". It is not called automatically.
Could there be different behavior if installed on win server2012r2? This is on win7.

Comment: With the uninstall on 2012r2 earlier today. I had an popup saying "No access to delete : Software\Microsoft"

Comment: During the uninstall?  That's really odd. I'll try to spin up a VM to reproduce today.  Something is very strange because I didn't see anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71951/discussion-between-stinus-and-christopher-painter).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see obviously wrong is that you think you are changing the Silverlight registry entries in the native 64 bit registry and the 32 bit Wow registry. Your install is x86 and you can't do that. If you're going to alter that key in the 32 bit world you just use the normal registry path and an x86 install maps it to WoW6432. So you have got two different components uninstalling the same thing, one of them incorrectly addressing the WoW6432 location directly. I don't know if this could screw things up but it's plainly wrong. You need an x64 setup for x64 systems, and as a matter of customer security I would not change those policy settings without making it clear to the customer.

The only other odd thing is that you seem to be installing the uninstall.bat file twice. What's in it? If it uninstalls the app, what's wronmg with using Control Panel? And hopefully that's not got anything that might be responsibe, if users are running that to do the uninstall.